# SHAP Summary plot for LIghtGBM

Tags: lightgbm, shap

How to explain below shap summary plot for each class. I have checked below document for the explanation still is not very clear to me. Please explain.

https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/tree_based_models/Census%20income%20classification%20with%20LightGBM.html

[image]

Comment: In this case, it is mostly like the feature importance. So, in your figure and based on SHAP calculation, the relationship feature has the most importance on decisions and the country feature has the lowest importance. It also can show that the impact of features on each class are equal.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but for lgbm classifier, the `shap_values` obtained from `shap.TreeExplainer()` are a list of `len = number of classes`. So for a binary case, it's a list of 2 arrays, where one array is the negative of the other (as expected). As a result, plotting it as is does not provide a lot of information as the bars of each class for a feature are equal in length.

To get more information from the shap summary plot, use the index associated with your class of interest (e.g., 1 for positive class).

Code example for binary classification -

```
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(lgbm_model.shap_values(x_test))
len(shap_values) == 2
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], x_test)
```

Answer (score -1):

'Relationship' is most important variable for classifying both the class as width is maximum for both- blue and red.

For any variable, lets say age if blue part is more than red, we can say variable is more important to identify class 0, compare to class 1. In your case all variables seems like there is no such property.